# Any popular implementations of alternatives to polar and cartesian coordinate systems?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, vector-analysis

Do you know of any challenges to Cartesian coordinate algorithm?

So there are these two ways to graph cartestian XYZ or POLAR. On earth we use GPS LAT and LONG. 100% mastery of that concept evades me.
So without standard implementation sometimes the Y is vertical while other times Z is vertical. In some implementations Z buffer is used.

Well I think I would like to create my own system ensuring that X, Y, Z, are positive always and not decimal points. This is for computer systems. If I need I decimal version I feel I can use decimalshifts to represent that rather than raddix notation in larger scales so 10 = 1 for example then 11 could represent 1.1.

Since I limit the points to being comprised of integers I think I can use 2 bits to represent the 4 quadrants or 8 bits in an XQUADRANT System to represent 16 channels of cartesian coordinates. Or I can use the bits to infere flags about the location like usablity and usage(4 flags).

What this means is that no distance will be negative and the directions are considered as flags in my class definition.

Now the problem of memdumping or DMA is where I feel theres a problem when one makes their own method of graphing for computers. Also I have to consider if its BIG ENDIAN LITTLE ENDIAN and/or OUTER INDIAN (leftHand_X16 vs rightHand_BIN)

Also when is that parse applied for the dev/dsp 16 bits have the 8bits swapped so pcm data is {0 64} in 8 bit but in 16 bit data becomes 0 ($64X255$) instead of remaining {0 64} but does that carry into 32 bit this is similar to how the quandrants are re-directed to other "texture" locations

To remedy divisions I considered fractional digit representation as opposed to decimal. Also the MORE operation is useful especially when dealing with irrational numbers like $142857000000/999999$ or any repeating fration divides by a repeating pattern of the (BASE-1) so consider $420/999$ or $DEADBEEF/FFFFFFFF$

So the MORE FUNCTION works as follow $2$~$|6$ is $2+20+200+2000+20000+200000$ or simpler $222222$. In base $10$ whereas $"11 MORE 2" 11$~$|2$ is the equivalent of $11+110$ or $121$ as opposed to the lexical inference of $1111$.

Since the ~ is not overloaded as so in any progamming language I know and | is confusing for the OR or BITWISE OR || operations as well as piping data. Do you think any other characters would be better for the MORE COMMAND.

Comment: This will definitely alter the translation matrices so a game like ZeVeRoH would like fuzzy that set up.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this more suited for Stack Overflow?

Comment: I like how rotation of 1/7 and 6/7 by 1k multiples is awesome. I call these symetrically opposed numbers in base 10 whereas EV are symetrically opposed in SET of {A-Z} and DEADBEEF and 21524110 are in HEXADECIMAL

Comment: I think you could post it on stack overflow as a computing question but I definitely think the keywords here are more suited for the question

Answer (score 1):

Think of an electrical field formed between two equally but oppositely charged, cylindrical wires that are parallel to each other.  The electric potential field between them is described by a solution to the Laplace Equation in [bipolar coordinates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_coordinates), where one set of level surfaces are circular arcs sharing the same pair of endpoints ("poles", corresponding to the wires in the electrical model) and the orthogonal surfaces are circles that loop through the space between the poles.

Comment: Hmm. Ive seen the magnetism field usually in cartesian POLAR graphing is more like an animation over time or a gear rotating. Sound is another graph - spectographs and frequency response charts. I like the idea of restrained points with weight values. Your post reminded me of fractals and other Procedureal Art

Comment: How do I graph that way do I get like a tack and rubber band Or use a real magnet? I cant imagine a etch-a-sketch method.